# Can't get audio and video speeds to play at original speeds

Tags: video, audio, linux, lightworks

When I import audio and video from different sources into a project, I can't get them to play at the corrects speeds.

For example, if I play the video in vlc player, it plays fine, if I play the audio file in vlc, it plays fine. But when I import the audio and video file into lightworks, either the video plays fine and the audio plays fast, or the video plays slow and the audio plays fine.

How do I get both the audio and video to play at the correct speeds at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes this will happen from a verity of reasons. Sometimes the clocks are different. A lot of time it comes down to manual re-syncing.
Pick 2 sync points for the Video and the same 2 points for the audio. Make sure they are as far away as possible. Now divide the duration in frames between the 2

```
V dur / A dur = ratio
```

Now you have the ratio you should speed up or slow down the sound (sound is more pliable). Good Luck!